# Async Action with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React component that's connected to Redux store. I'm fetching resources(posts) in the `componentWillMount` life-cycle method.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.fetchPosts();
}
```

The component will subscribe to Redux store and getting `isFetching` and `posts` from the store.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    posts: getAllPosts(state),
    isFetching: getIsFetchingPosts(state),
  }
}
```

I'd like to show a spinner when it's still fetching, so in the `render` method I'd like to do this.

```
render() {
   if (this.props.isFetching) {
     return <Spinner />
   }

   return this.props.posts.map(post => <PostItem key={post.id}{...post}/>)
}
```

BUT if I console.log `isFetching` in the `render` method, first it shows `false` and then`true` and then finally `false`.

Ideally when this container renders for the first time `isFetching` state is already set to `true` and showing the spinner. What changes do I need to make to make that happen?

Here is code for the action creator and reducers

```
/*** Action Creator ***/
export const fetchPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: REQUEST_POSTS,
  });

  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${API_URL}/posts`,
  })
  .then(({data}) => {
    dispatch({
      type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
      payload: data.posts,
    })
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    // some error handling.
  });
}


/*** Reducers ***/
const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  allIds: [],
  byId: {},
};

const isFetching = (state = initialState.isFetcthing, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return true;
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const allIds = (state = initialState.allIds, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return action.payload.map(post => post.id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const byId = (state = initialState.byId, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return action.payload.reduce((nextState, post) => {
        nextState[post.id] = post;
        return nextState;
      }, {...state});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const posts = combineReducers({
  isFetching,
  allIds,
  byId,
});

export default posts;


/*** Selectors in 'posts.js' file ***/

export const getAllPosts = (state) => {
  const { allId, byId } = state;
  return allIds.map(id => byId[id]);
}

/*** rootReducer file ***/
import posts, * as fromPosts from './posts';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts,
})

export default rootReducer;

export const getAllPosts = (state) => {
  return fromPosts.getAllPosts(state.posts);
};
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not really clear, what fetchPosts is, you don't provide it in mapStateToProps. And what is the connections between posts from state and fetchPosts (does function update state?). Could you clarify this?

Comment: Having `isFetching=false` at the start is an ok behavior as it just means that the action hasn't hit the reducer yet ie `render` was called before  the `fetchPosts` had set the flag to true.

Answer (score 1):

The plain answer is that this is the expected behaviour, given your implementation. You're mapping the `isFetching` state to a prop. Here's what's happening:

1. The initial value of `isFetching` in the state tree is `false`, so the `isFetching` prop value is `false`, so it renders as `false`.
2. You dispatch an action which changes `isFetching` to `true` in the state tree. This new state is mapped to a new `isFetching` prop value of `true`, which causes a re-render, where it renders as `true`.
3. You (asynchronously) dispatch another action which changes `isFetching` back to `false` in the state tree. Same as in (2), this causes a re-render, with `isFetching` as `false`.

The plain solution if you want simply a render of `true, false`*, with the current implementation, is to set `isFetching` to `true` in your reducer's initial state.

Whether or not this implementation makes sense on a design level for this component is a broader question, that there's not enough context to answer here :-)

***update** for completeness I should say I don't know if the `render()` function would be called twice, with `isFetching` resolved as `true,false` or three times with `true,true,false` in this case. I suspect that react-redux may optimise the rendering of the component such that no re-render occurs if the mapped `isFetching` prop changes from `true`->`true`, but don't know this for sure - would be grateful and interested if you could let me know what your logging outputs?

In any case, at the DOM level certainly only two renders would occur, due to the standard react virtual-DOM diffing optimisation, so in effect the result is the same either way

Comment: thank you for the answer! I just updated the question. "Ideally when this container renders for the first time isFetching state is already set to true and showing the spinner. What changes do I need to make to make that happen?" Do you have some ideas for this? I'm using `react-router` by the way.

Comment: No problem. To be honest, this is something I've struggled with myself in my own reducer designs - how to keep an initial state, and reset that initial state for each new render of the component. You could go the way of setting the initial state so `isFetching` is true, and then making sure this is reset to `true` in the state tree before you render this component subsequent times. This could be a bit laborious, depending on your design. Another, simpler way, is just to keep `isFetching` as an internal state on the component, resetting it each time the component mounts using getInitialState()

Comment: (cont) I think this is really one of those design choices without a clear answer. It just depends on your app :-) For me, as I say, where to keep these small-ish self-contained UI states is one of the big open questions when writing an app with redux.